# Ordering by relationship column with big collections

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am currently working on a ping system for various websites which pings via an external application certain hosts simoultanisly.

Those results get stored in a MySQL Database.
In order to show those results semi-live (Polling) I am using Laravel & Livewire (with some other addons)

I want to sort/order my list so that those who have the highest ping, will come on top.
I have tried various methods and searched through Stackoverflow through. To no avail I have had any luck on the actual sorting.

Note that the pingrequests table has **A LOT** of records.

**Livewire blade**

```php
            @foreach(\App\Models\Host::select('hosts.*')
            ->join('pingrequests', 'pingrequests.host_id', '=', 'hosts.id')
            ->groupBy('hosts.id')
            ->orderByRaw('max(pingrequests.speed) asc')
            ->get()
            as $host)
```

**Database structure of Hosts (simplified)**

```
id | ip
----------------
1  | 192.1.1.1
2  | google.com
3  | google.nl
```

**Database structure of pingrequests (simplified)**

```
id | speed | hostid
----------------
1  | 64444 | 1
2  | 64444 | 1
3  | 66535 | 1
```

Comment: Hi, did you try `orderBy('pingrequests.speed', 'asc')`?

Comment: Yep, but due to the nature of orderby it will try to order the whole table (Which is ALOT). Maybe I should try chopping it up a bit and see if that works.

Comment: @Christiaan What do you mean by getting maximum value without looping through all of them?. Do you have any sort of paginatino in this section? I would suggest saving `maximum` value with `related id` to a temporary space. Then with every new record, you compare with this max value. So techinically you only have to run the task above once.

Comment: @HuyPhạm It does not even sort it properly on the initial ordering. The highest should be on top. But that does not happen for some reason.